# How can I give someone view-only access to my Mac?

Tags: ssh, vnc, remote-access

I need to share my screen with someone, but I don't want him having access to my computer.

I know there is a screen sharing option in system preferences(10.6), but if I disable control, TightVNC gives an error about the method of authentication not being supported.

Since all I'm going to do is fumble around in terminal, ssh is also fine.

The key point is that I don't trust the viewer with my computer, so I need restricted or no access for him.

I want to have someone "looking over my shoulder" while doing a complex compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Skype to share your screen ( http://www.skype.com/allfeatures/screensharing/ )

Comment: iChat can do this as well. So I guess it depends on the viewer which is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

[Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/download/index.aspx) has an option for viewing only under **Extras -> Options -> Security**.

[image]

Comment: No way to do that with the built in sharing? config file or something like that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the built-in sharing, but TeamViewer requires no additional configuration or port forwarding.